# Perform action after end of the sound

Tags: java, swing, audio, action, javasound

I am able to play sounds in my Java Swing application right now usind JavaSound and code from [Java play WAV sound file](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml). What I currently want to do is:

Play a sound; after the sound is finished I want to play another sound (which is the action).
So basically, in steps:

1. Play a sound.  (I know how long this sound takes - 4 seconds).
2. After end of sound.
3. Perform action (e.g. play another sound).

I tried several options, delays, threads but couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: There are several ways of playing a sound clip in Java. Which one did you use?

Comment: This one: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the good solution of Abbas, I can suggest to periodically check if the thread you use to play the file is alive.

Looking the tutorial provided by you, the main program creates a new instance of the thread class and uses the `start()` method to start the thread. So, you can check if the thread is still alive. When the thread is dead you can do what you want. For example:

```
    AePlayWave apw = new AePlayWave("test.wav");
    apw.start();

    try{
        boolean alive = apw.isAlive();
        while(alive){
            //check periodically if the thread is alive         
            alive = apw.isAlive();
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);

            }

    }

    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//do other action..
```

When the `apw` thread is dead (then boolean `alive` is false) and the program is quitting from the `while` loop, you can perform what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, a `DataLine` object is being used to play a sound. The `DataLine` object has a method call `addLineListener` which takes an object that implements the `LineListener` interface and exposes events such as `start` and `stop` that you can use to perform your action or play another sound.

What you need to do is:

1. Implement the `LineListener` interface in your class
2. Subscribe to an update event by calling the `addLineListener` method with `this`
   argument
3. Implement the `update` method of the `LineListener` interface
4. Test the event in `update` method and provide the action you require

[Here's a link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.sound.sampled/LineaddLineListenerLineListenerlistener.htm) that demonstrates processing `LineListener` events in the `update` method.

Comment: Very good. I didn't know about the LineListener. ;-) But, if we want an alternative solution, maybe the main program could wait for the thread (I see it from the tutorial provided by the OP) until is alive, and then, when the thread is dead, the OP can perform another action. I don't know what really the OP has done in terms of thread, but don't you think this could be an alternative?

Comment: That's another valid approach However, I find the update method very convenient and implementing LineListener less intrusive to the current structure.